# Mac Osx Lion gets stuck on loading screen

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, boot-camp, imac

I have an IMac Pro.

I wanted to install Windows 7, so I created a partition with `Bootcamp`, and installed Windows 7. Everything was fine, Windows was working and the Mac too.

After two days, I started the Mac, and it just got stuck at the loading screen.

I waited for one hour, and it didn't start. The 2nd time I booted the computer in Mac after that problem, it got stuck again, and a rare loading bar appeared.

Since that day, Mac doesn't boot, I don't know if the bootcamp or Windows is doing something to my Mac partition.

What could be happening?

---

**Edit:**

I tried to repair the OS, I verified the disk, and repaired it.
It says that there is a problem with the B-Tree catalog, and the system can not be repaired...

Answer (score 0):

Try booting in safe mode.

**Boot into safe mode:**

1. Completely shut down your Mac
2. Turn your mac on
3. Immediately after you hear the startup tone, hold the Shift key. The Shift key should be held as soon as possible after the startup tone, but not before the tone.
4. Release the Shift key when you see the gray Apple icon and the progress indicator (looks like a spinning gear).

This should allow you to get into your computer.  Once you're in, reboot your computer.  See if this fixes it.

Comment: Ill try it, ill give you the results tomorrow